# Convert unix timestamp to hh:mm:ss:SSS (where SSS is milliseconds) in AWK

Tags: linux, awk, timestamps, time

How can I convert unix timestamp to hh:mm:ss:SSS (where SSS is milliseconds) in AWK.

For example:

```
echo 1456478048306 > time
cat time | awk ....... > readable_time_format
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `date`:

```
d=1456478048306
s=${d%???}
ms=${d#"$s"}

date -d "@$s" +"%F %T.$ms %z"
# or:
date -d "$s.$ms" '+%F %T.%3N %z'
```

With BSD `date`:

```
date -r "$s" +"%F %T.$ms %z"
```

With GNU `awk` and recent versions of `mawk` (since `1.3.4 20121129`):

```
echo 1456478048306 | awk '{
  print strftime("%F %T." substr($0,length-2) " %z", substr($0, 1, length-3))}'
```

For portability, `perl` may be your best bet:

```
echo 1456478048306 | perl -MPOSIX -lne '
  print strftime "%F %T.$2 %z", localtime $1 if /(.+)(.{3})/'
```

Here giving my preferred more conventional and less ambiguous format:

```
2016-02-26 09:14:08.306 +0000
```

but of course, you can adjust the `strftime` format to your preference.

Comment: mawk (except Debian of course) provides strftime since late 2012. ymmv.

Comment: @ThomasDickey. Thanks, added. You have a typo in the CHANGES file btw (`s/strtime/strftime/`).

Comment: I noticed that when I commented...

Answer (score 1):

If you are unconcerned about timezones and leap seconds, and for some reason your awk does not support `strftime`, you can calculate it directly:

```
awk '{ t=$1;sss=(t % 1000); t/=1000; ss=(t%60); t/=60; mm=(t%60);
  t/=60; hh=(t%24); printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n",hh,mm,ss,sss); }'
```